# swift. UIBezierPath borderColor

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uibezierpath

I'm trying to set UItextField with TopRight and BottomLeft Corner radius, but get translucent corners. The picture below will make my problem cleaner

[image]

Tried to set strokeColor and borderColor, without any success.

```
let c = UIColor.orangeColor()
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:field_name.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[UIRectCorner.TopRight, .BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
maskLayer.fillColor = c.CGColor
field_name.layer.mask = maskLayer
field_name.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

If someone helped me with the code, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: are you doing this in the text field's subclass or in another class?

Comment: I'm doing this in  viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

```
textField.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
textField.layer.borderColor = YourColor.cgColor
```